# is there a way for javascript regex to replace a character in the second half of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been having trouble making a regular expression which changes "_" to " ". For example the string below:

```
<h2><a href=?ref=ref_url&?title=title_name_unoriginal>7s6s**title_name_unoriginal**7s6s<h2>
```

I'd like to change the starred text so that the underscores become spaces. I added `7s6s` so that I could identify that region in a regular expression:

```
/7s6s[a-zA-Z0-9_]+7s6s/
```

So I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to change `title_name_unoriginal` to `title name unoriginal`. Note: there's a `title_name_unoriginal` that comes right before which I don't want to change. Also for the regex, the number of underscores can be from 0-100s. so it may also be `title_name_un_ori_ginal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str.replace(/7s6s.+7s6s/g,function($0){return $0.replace(/_/g," ")})
```

Its pretty simple what is doing; first it takes all the texts that start and end with 7s6s (regex: 7s6s.+7s6s), then because the function **replace** accepts a function as a second argument to perform the replacement, we can make a replacement over the selected text. In this case is just another regex that replaces "_" with " "

Comment: thank you this worked perfectly..gonna try to understand it now

Comment: I added a little explication, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

After the last "/", add "g".

You need to use the "global" modifier if you want a regular expression to continue after it has found a match.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use replace instead?

```
var linktext = document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML;
linktext.replace("_", " ");
```

Comment: innerHTML is a property, not a method.

Comment: @IvanCastellanos - ack, I always do that. Thank you.